# How the cpu_time implemented in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

We want to  [cpu_time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) implement the  cpu_time in MySQL ,is there anyone know how this cpu_time  implemented in SQL Server?

I want to know the implementation mechanism of cpu_time in SQL server, and then port the same function to MySQL. I understand that cpu_time in SQL server is implemented by cpu time-related API of the  OS, but I don’t know which OS API it is. If I know the OS API for implementing the cpu_time in SQL Server ,then I sure I can get the equivalent one in linux for MySQL

Comment: What do you mean how is it implemented in sql server? Do you want source code or are you trying to understand how it is useful or are you confused by the results? Your question is not very clear (to me anyways).

Comment: Also, you mentioned MySQL but tagged your question with Microsoft SQL Server. Correct your question or tag.

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear.  @Igor

Comment: Why would the API used by MSSQL matter? The MySQL and MSSQL engines are not comparable, so you'd never expect the same time for requests anyway. You can use any API or approach you like to measure durations. Most probably SQL Server uses `QueryPerformanceCounter` on Windows, just like other applications that measure durations do. Measuring execution time is not specific to database engines.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks ,do you know the equivalent  of  QueryPerformanceCounter in linux?